# simple css text image layout

Tags: image, text

I am having trouble getting some text to be next to an image. I have it working on one site: http://puckpros.edkatzman.com/

but not on another: http://petra.edkatzman.com/

and I can't see the difference. Can another pair of eyes help?

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tangobango/rK2mG/

HTML:

```
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <div id="front-page">
                <div id="owner-photo ">
                    <img src="http://petra.edkatzman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Ed-headshot-small.jpg" alt="Ed Katzman" >
                </div>
                <div id="owner-description ">

                        <h1><span class="drop-cap">Hi! </span>My name is Michael Jennings, 
                        the owner and master craftsman of Petra Stoneworks. I have over 25 
                        years experience working with a wide range of both valuable and everyday stone pieces.</h1>

                    <h3>We specialize in the expert repair of stone objects and the creation 
                    of original pieces. Have a look at the portfolio of our work and contact 
                    us with any questions or to start a discussion of how we might help you.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </div><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

CSS:

```
#front-page {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    overflow: hidden;


}

#owner-photo {
    width:246px;
    height:246px;
    float:left;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for including the jsFiddle. That was very helpful. Your problem is a simple typo.

```
<div id="owner-photo ">
```

There is a space in the id attribute. Delete that space and the div should float.

I am not really sure what the outlook is for your page but you might want to move the owner-photo ID onto the image itself and remove the potentially unnecessary div from your code.

Answer (score 0):

The diference are:

First, put float:left in id="owner-photo"

```
<div id="owner-photo " style="float: left;">
<img src="http://petra.edkatzman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Ed-headshot-small.jpg" alt="Ed Katzman">
</div>
```

Second:

I don't know why but, don't use <-h1>, use <-p>.

In the example of http://puckpros.edkatzman.com/

first there is:

```
<img class="left_image" src="http://puckpros.edkatzman.com/wp-content/themes/PuckPros/images/services.png">
```

and then:

```
<p>something</p>
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Great suggestion. It does fix it in the jsfiddle, but when I put it into my wordpress page it still doesn't work. I'm trying to dig into it. I have u8pdated the fiddle. If you know WP , mayybe you have some thoughts.

Comment: if you are still using <div> try modify the div properties at the css template (style.css). Add an element "float:left;" in "#owner-photo" css div property, and upload again, I'll look it.
--Edited
You already resolved! Congrats!